# THREE.js Editor: How to access main script in an example

Tags: javascript, three.js, editor

I can open the THREE.js editor at http://threejs.org/editor/.
I can open an example app e.g. PONG.
I can activate interactive animation by clicking on Play in the menu bar.
I can deactivate the animation by clicking on Stop in the menu bar.

I wish to edit the Main Script (the "Scene/Game logic" script) using the Editor as per this illustration:- https://plus.google.com/photos/+ricardocabello/albums/6104607340192211937/6104607354618509202?pid=6104607354618509202&oid=113862800338869870683

I can access Script controls for graphical objects. But how do I access the Main Script?

I am using
Opera version 28.0.1750.51 
Laptop System:  Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha. Got it.

Within the "SCENE" panel on the RHS of the Editor it is necessary to select the "Scene" object. This will add another panel called "SCENE" and below that there will be added another panel called "SCRIPT".  (May need to scroll down to see it). The loaded "Game logic" script will be indicated. Just click on the "Edit" button to display the javascript in the main window of the Editor.

Comment: i want to "export" the 3d model from the threejs editor to codepen, but no script exists in this part of the editor? :(

Comment: @oldboy sorry I dont know how to do that.

Comment: all good. i noticed in the editor there is an option of exporting the geometry, object, and scene, and i believe these spit out JSON files. are these the json files we need to move the project elsewhere?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the original question.  You need to ask a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

Go on the Pong project. From there you can click on file-> Publish. Unzip the file then you can see app.js in js folder. It's the script that is controlling the animation. It's the only way I know to view the source. Hope this help! :)

Comment: Thanks but I expect to edit the script using the THREE.js editor as illustrated here:- https://plus.google.com/photos/+ricardocabello/albums/6104607340192211937/6104607354618509202?pid=6104607354618509202&oid=113862800338869870683